# Custom phonetic analysis in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-phonetic

In our service we are trying to port a customization of the "nysiis" phonetic algorithm to Elasticsearch.

Our algorithm performs this name transformation:

> given a list of "Surnames" and "Firstnames", such as "[Smith]" and
>   "[John]", takes the "nysiis" phonetic encoder on the first surname,
>   and concatenates it to the lowercase first initial of the first
>   firstname.

Hence:

```
nysiis(Surnames[0]) + lower(Firstnames[0][0])
```

So the result with "John Smith" would be "SNATHj"

I know ES supports the nyyis token filter https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-phonetic-token-filter.html

but I wonder what is the best way to implement a custom analyzer that automatically perform the above transformation.

---

Note: I guess, if needed, we can already provide ES with a simple structure:

```
{"surname": "Smith", "initial_first_name": "j"}
```

Comment: The better question is what do you want to do with the combined values afterwards?

Comment: An external library, ML-based, has been trained exactly with this particular transformation, hence I need to be able to search for all the records matching this particular form of phonetic-block. So to answer your specific question I would then, given a surname and a firstname transform them at search time and use to match all the records falling into the same phonetic block.